# How to get this query with the use of extended group by functions

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to write a query that returns this:

```
DNAME                                    G TITLE            SALARY
---------------------------------------- - ------------ ----------
                                                           1059000
                                           Analyst          107000
                                           Manager          395000
                                           Developer        152000
                                           Programmer       152500
                                           Sr. Analyst      252500
                                         F                  366500
                                         M                  692500
Risk and Compliance                                         264500
Finance and Accounting Excellence                           395000
Internal Audit and Financial Controls                       399500

11 rows selected.
```

**UPDATE!!!** Ok so I was playing around with different queries and this is the closest I have to the above output...it looks like its still missing the sum of all salaries for the first returned row...and I believe in order to make the generated output to display in that format is through the use of the group by cube function however I've tried different combinations of group by group sets cube to no avail...any ideas???

> select dname, gender, title, salary from (select dname, gender, title,
>   grouping_id(dname, gender, title) as "group_id", sum(salary) as salary from azdepartment 
>   join azconsultant on azdepartment.did=azconsultant.did group by grouping sets(dname, 
>   gender, title) having grouping_id(dname, gender, title)>0);

```
DNAME                                    G TITLE            SALARY
---------------------------------------- - ------------ ----------
                                           Manager          395000
                                           Programmer       152500
                                           Sr. Analyst      252500
                                           Analyst          107000
                                           Developer        152000
Finance and Accounting Excellence                           395000
Risk and Compliance                                         264500
Internal Audit and Financial Controls                       399500
                                         M                  692500
                                         F                  366500

10 rows selected.
```

Comment: SQL is not a report creation tool, it is a data selection tool. The desired result doesn't really make sense as a query result (not saying it is impossible to achieve, but it is like using a car to crack a walnut) - it is a combination of 4 different queries. Why not run four separate queries? Or combine the results of four with `UNION`s?

Comment: its just the required output that was required of me so I have no idea why they wanted it like that

Comment: But did they say "write a single SQL statement to give this result" or did they say "query the database to give this result"? There is an important difference.

Comment: I believe its through a single sql statement. Your query statement below is actually pretty close, it looks like a mirror image of the answer except the first rows value from the correct output is different

Comment: I shall play with it and let you know

Comment: I also posted the output of your code below

Answer (score 1):

Done using `UNION`s:

```
  select '' as dname, '' as gender, '' as title, sum(salary) as salary 
  from azconsultant
union 
  select '' as dname, '' as gender,       title, sum(salary) as salary 
  from azconsultant
  group by title 
union 
  select '' as dname,       gender, '' as title, sum(salary) as salary 
  from azconsultant
  group by gender 
union 
  select dname,       '' as gender, '' as title, sum(salary) as salary 
  from azdepartment 
  join azconsultant on azdepartment.did=azconsultant.did 
  group by dname
order by 1 DESC, 2 DESC , 3 DESC;
```

**UPDATE** Added ORDER BY, tested and fiddle added: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3fa8b/4

Comment: heres your statement ran with my data